# CSRF 403 error after clearing a form with javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a form displayed in html that a user can enter information into that I build a graph out of. After clearing the form and trying to resubmit the POST request, i get a 403 error "Forbidden (403),CSRF verification failed. Request aborted."

I am using js from here: http://javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-reset-form.phtml. My code runs the rest of the time (my initial use of the form). But i always get the error after I clear the form.

Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like the form reset method is also clearing the hidden CSRF token field.

Comment: a form reset will clear all 'value' fields from your chosen form, including your token value. consider removing the clear form button or using JS to clear the form fields selectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to the comments.
Yes, the js was removing any "hidden" values as well which was causing the error. Removing that line fixed the issue. Thank you!